# Think Python exercise 6.1

Tags: python

This is an exercise 6.1 in the book "Think Python". The question is to find the print result.

This is what I can get so far.

- x = 1, y = 2
- bring to a(x, y), return 4
- b(z), return z**2 + z

I couldn't find the valve z from c(x, y, z) function.

```py
def b(z):
        prod = a(z, z)
        print(z, prod)
        return prod

def a(x, y):
        x = x + 1
        return x * y

def c(x, y, z):
        total = x + y + z
        square = b(total)**2
        return square

x = 1
y = x + 1

print(c(x, y+3, x+y))
```

Comment: I don't understand the question.  Can't you "find the print result" by just running the code?  `(9, 90)
8100`  The `z` parameter for `c` is the `x+y` that's passed in on the last line (so it'll be 3).

Comment: Thanks. I was stuck with functions didn't take a look at print operator.

Answer (score 0):

The x and y in `def a(x, y):` are not the same x and y defined elsewhere in the script.  It might as well say `def a(j, k):`.  When you see `prod = a(z, z)`, you need to know what the value of z is, and then go to the definition of `def a(j, k):` and think `j = z` and `k = z`.

If we just tell you what the output is, then you wouldn't learn to "Think Python"

Comment: Thanks. I didn't consider the start process from the print operator and stuck with functions. It's pretty straight forward and I should have figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

It can be useful to organize functions on the stack to better understand which calls which:

-main-
c(x,y,z)
b(z)
a(x,y)